# How to install clang on ubuntu14.04

Tags: ubuntu, clang, llvm-clang

I want to learn llvm so I have to install clang in my ubuntu 14.04,but I encounter some problems.Here it is:

when I execute command:`sudo apt-get install clang-3.5` I just get some error message like follow:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  clang-3.5 : Depends:
libclang1-3.5 (= 1:3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be
installed
Depends: libobjc-4.8-dev but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
 packages.
```

and then I try to install libclang1-3.5,so I execute command:

```
sudo apt-get install libclang1-3.5
```

and then I got another error message like before:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libclang1-3.5 :
Depends: libobjc-4.8-dev but it is not going to be installed E: Unable
to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

then I execute command:

```
sudo apt-get install libobjc-4.8-dev
```

this time get error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libobjc-4.8-dev :
Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
is to be installed
Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libobjc4 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
broken packages.
```

after `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-dev`
get some error messages again

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32gcc-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: lib32gomp1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: lib32itm1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: lib32atomic1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: lib32asan0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32asan0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: lib32quadmath0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libx32gcc-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: lib32gomp1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: lib32itm1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: lib32atomic1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: lib32asan0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32asan0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: lib32quadmath0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what should I do now?

==============================================
after executing command sudo apt-get purge gcc* I got follow messages,it seems encounter some errors.

```
zhangkehu@ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get purge gcc*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libx32gcc-4.7-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-gconf-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-pa' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-libtagc-prof' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.8-jdk-aarch64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libhfgcc1-armel-dcv1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-pt' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.7' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.8' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.9' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-aarch64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'logcentral' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gconf2' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.4-locales' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-ru' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.4-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'lib32gcc-4.7-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'guile-gnome2-gconf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcovr' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcal-common' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'pulseaudio-module-gconf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'java-gcj-compat' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-sk' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-sl' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcr-3-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-jre-headless' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-so' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-plugin-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-sr' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-sv' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-svgcairo-dev-0.12.1-becda' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcrypt-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libtagc0-ruby' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.9-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-th' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-armel-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-tr' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'kjumpingcube' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'eclipse-rcp-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'tagcoll' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-source' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'java-gcj-compat-headless' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgconfmm-2.6-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-ur' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'icedtea-gcjwebplugin' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-mingw-w64-bootstrap' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libtagc0-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gconf-service-backend' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'logcheck-database' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-powerpc64le-linux-gnu-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'lib32gcc1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-tagcloud-perl' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gconf2-common' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'python-pygccxml' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-snapshot' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.6-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-2.0-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgc-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgconf2.0-cil-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'pulseaudio-module-gconf-dbg' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libx32gcc-4.8-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libvomsjapi-java-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-avr' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-data' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-gconf-dev-0.12.1.1-4d3b6' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.4-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-svgcairo-prof' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.6-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-gconf-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsac-java-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'fcitx-libs-gclient' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.8-jdk-powerpc64le-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgnome2-gconf-perl' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcal' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcap' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-arm64-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-1.1-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-jdk' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'lib32gcc-4.8-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'colorgcc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'sagcad-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-svgcairo-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'lib64gcc1-powerpc-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'compizconfig-backend-gconf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgc1c2' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgc1c3' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc-4.8-dev-ppc64el-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcin-qt4-immodule' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-ptbr' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.6-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcfilms' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-2.0-0' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'git-remote-gcrypt' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcdw' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-arm-none-eabi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-powerpc-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libxmlsec1-gcrypt' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libqtgconf-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-armel-dcv1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libhfgcc1-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.5-arm-linux-gnueabi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.8-jdk' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcu-dbg' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsfgcc1-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-opt' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'xgc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsaxon-java-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.6-source' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-dbg' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'python-argcomplete' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-1.9-0' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libextutils-pkgconfig-perl' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-libtagc-prof-0.12.0-7e84b' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcstar' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'fcitx-table-bingchan' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgconf2-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'pngcrush' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'lib64gcc1-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-2.0-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc-4.7-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-mingw-w64-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-docs' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-2.0-0c2a' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcin' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libtagc0-ruby1.8' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'llvm-gcc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgctp-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'pngcheck' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'nagcon' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgctp0d' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'r-cran-mgcv' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'lib64gcc1-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.8-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-2.0-0c2' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libdesktop-agnostic-cfg-gconf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcin-tables' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcj14-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-fi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libswt3.2-gtk-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-fr' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-gconf-prof-0.12.1.1-4d3b6' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'eclipse-jdt-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcalcli' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-gd' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'ggcov' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.4' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.8' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc1-ppc64el-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libxerces2-java-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'ant-optional-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.4-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcr-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-he' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-hi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.4-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-gck-1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-locales' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-hu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsigc++-1.2-5c102' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-mingw-w64-i686' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcu-plugin' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.9-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-id' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.8-jre-lib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'logcheck' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgconf-bridge-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-it' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcr-3-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcin-chewing' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcrypt-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-4.8-jre-headless' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcin-data' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'eclipse-platform-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.7-multilib' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcolor2' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.5-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gconf' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-powerpc64le-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.5-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcal0' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcj-powerpc64le-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcr-base-3-1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.8-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-uuagc-cabal-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gceph' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgconfmm-2.6-dev' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcin-gtk3-immodule' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-m68hc1x' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcc-4.8-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-svgcairo-prof-0.12.1-becda' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gir1.0-gconf-2.0' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-lt' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcrystal' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'eclipse-pde-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsfgcc1-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgconfmm-2.6-1c2' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-uuagc-cabal-dev-1.0.4.0-b5c8b' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'logcentral-tools' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.6-locales' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-4.8-powerpc64le-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-mr' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcrypt11-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcl-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-multilib-powerpc-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcrypt11' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-nb' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libtagc0' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-ast' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-gconf-prof' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-nl' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcr-3-common' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcompris-sound-nn' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-base' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcj11' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'ecj-bootstrap-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'librepository-java-gcj' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcj14' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgcr-ui-3-1' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'gccgo-go' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libsfgcc-4.7-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'gcc*'
Note, selecting 'libgck-1-doc' for regex 'gcc*'
Package 'libjaxp1.3-java-gcj' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libsaxon-java-gcj' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libsigc++-2.0-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libsigc++-2.0-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtagc0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtagc0-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtagcoll2-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libx32gcc-4.7-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libx32gcc-4.8-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libx32gcc1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libx32gcc1-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libxerces2-java-gcj' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java-gcj' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'logcheck' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'logcheck-database' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pulseaudio-module-gconf' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pulseaudio-module-gconf-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'colorgcc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compizconfig-backend-gconf' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'docbook-xsl-saxon-gcj' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fcitx-libs-gclient' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fcitx-table-bingchan' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gcal' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gcal-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gcalcli' is not installed, so not removed
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt libapt-pkg4.12 (due to apt) libc6 (due to apt) libgcc1 (due to apt) libstdc++6 (due to apt) gnupg (due to apt) base-files base-passwd libdebconfclient0 (due to base-passwd) bash debianutils (due to
  bash) dash (due to bash) libtinfo5 (due to bash) bsdutils coreutils libacl1 (due to coreutils) libattr1 (due to coreutils) libselinux1 (due to coreutils) dpkg (due to dash) diffutils libbz2-1.0 (due to
  dpkg) liblzma5 (due to dpkg) zlib1g (due to dpkg) tar (due to dpkg) e2fsprogs e2fslibs (due to e2fsprogs) libblkid1 (due to e2fsprogs) libcomerr2 (due to e2fsprogs) libss2 (due to e2fsprogs) libuuid1
  (due to e2fsprogs) util-linux (due to e2fsprogs) findutils grep install-info (due to grep) libpcre3 (due to grep) gzip hostname libc-bin libcap2 (due to libc-bin) login libpam0g (due to login)
  libpam-runtime (due to login) libpam-modules (due to login) mount libmount1 (due to mount) ncurses-bin perl-base sed tzdata (due to util-linux) debconf (due to util-linux) sysv-rc (due to util-linux)
  libncurses5 (due to util-linux) libslang2 (due to util-linux)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1636 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,222 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] yes
Abort.
```

Comment: you can go to https://askubuntu.com for this. This site is only for programming questions

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands to fix broken packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

See if it works.

EDIT: 
your could try these commands too

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
apt-get clear cache
```

EDIT#2:

With a text editor, edit your /etc/apt/sources.list file so that it has the following content :

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main universe 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main universe 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

###### For LLVM
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
```

(note: it's always good to create a backup of the sources.list before modifying it)

After that run all the commands at the top of this post (sudo apt-get update... sudo apt uprgrade... etc..etc..). Then run the command to download llvm. Hope it works.

Comment: It seems doesn't work for me,when executing 'apt-get clear cache' get error message:Invalid operation clear

Comment: @AlphaOF where the other commands successful? Also, did you add a custom ppa by any chance?

Comment: I'm using windows,my Ubuntu is a virtual machine run on VMWare and I used it not so much,I don't remember what I had done on my VM.The time when I run it is 4-5 months ago.By the way, command "appitude" is not work too.

Comment: @AlphaOF, Look at my second edit. ( the command is "aptitude" by the way. )

Comment: ,aha, failed again,I think it may my gcc version's problem,I'll uninstall it(version 4.8.4) and install 4.8.2.,first,I need uninstall it,but  I don't know how to uninstall it so I need find 'gcc' and remove them and then install 4.8.2. I'm very appreciate for your help,thanks very much.

Comment: zhangkehu@ubuntu:/$ gcc -v
The program 'gcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gcc
zhangkehu@ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: that's weird. try purging gcc with     sudo apt-get purge gcc*

Comment: It seems I need solve gcc problem first,o my god,I should ask some questions in ubuntu forum.

Comment: perhaps you should. my ubuntu knowledge only goes so far :)

Comment: @ travisjayday I edit my question's body again and input some error message I got after executing command 'sudo apt-get purge gcc*'

Comment: Did you ever replace your sources.list with the one I posted?